# Remove repeating rows, keeping only those with full columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
ID   Name     Value
1    John      44
1              44
2    Mike      235
3    Fred      32
4    Lena      11
4    Lena
```

I want to keep only those rows with full columns. So desired result is:

```
ID   Name     Value
1    John      44
2    Mike      235
3    Fred      32
4    Lena      11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the data with empty values and select only those rows where no empty values are present . Using `rowSums` this can be done as :

```
df[rowSums(df == "") == 0 , ]
#  ID Name Value
#1  1 John    44
#3  2 Mike   235
#4  3 Fred    32
#5  4 Lena    11
```

Another option is to turn the empty values to `NA` and use `na.omit` to remove such rows.

```
df[df == ''] <- NA
na.omit(df)
```